# How to do some sort of join query in firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to do some sort of join between two different collections in firestore based on `uid`.  I have reviews collection with each review having a uid. I want to use that uid to get the users detail information like, `username, photoURL`.

```
getUsersReviews(userId){
      const reviewsRef = this.afs.collection('users-reviews', ref => ref.where('uid', '==', userId) );
      reviewsRef.switchMap(reviews => {
        let userObservables = reviews.map(status => this.afs.doc(`users/${userId}`))
        return Observable.combineLatest(...userObservables)
          .map((...users) => {
            reviews.forEach((review, index) => {
              review.username = users[0][index].username;
              review.avatar = users[0][index].photoURL;
            });
            return reviews;          
          });
      });
    }
```

How can I get this to work? The above code doesn't work with errors such as `switchMap` doesn't exist on firestore collection.

```
 error TS2339: Property 'switchMap' does not exist on type 'AngularFirestoreCollection<{}>'.
```

Even though switchMap is imported.

Answer (score 1):

`AngularFirestoreCollection` is not an `Observable`, so there will not be a `switchMap` mehtod on it. See the implementation here: 
https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/a13bf9b10e78dc74a1bfe61fea22480d2da859c1/src/firestore/collection/collection.ts#L45

Use the `snapshotChanges` or `stateChanges` method of `AngularFirestoreCollection` to get an `Observable`, where you can use `switchMap`.